# extract a policy Id from the given string using RegEx

Tags: regex, ruby

I have to extract the given below string

```
PO-EXW1900000955/00/00
```

I have written the following regex

```
/(?<=Policy) \w+-\w+\/\w+\/\w+/
```

The above one works fine but I feel like I repeat this \w+ every single word. Is there any other better way to avoid this repeated \w+?

Comment: You need to give us the rules in order for us to make useful suggestions. Presumably the string of interest follows `"Policy "`. Your example shows the first 3 characters to be `"PO-"`. Are the characters before the hyphen always capital letters? How many might there be? Between the hyphen and first forward slash you have `"EXW1900000955"`. Is that length fixed? Does it always begin with 3 capital letters followed by digits? After that you have `"/00/00"`. Are there always 2 3-character substrings consisting of a forward slash and followed by two digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like I repeat this \w+ every single word. Is there any other better way to avoid this repeated \w+?

Yes! You could name the subpattern, then invoke it later:

```
/(?<=Policy) (?<word>\w+)-\g<word>\/\g<word>\/\g<word>/
```

or the prettified version:

```
%r{
  (?<word>
    \w+
  ){0}

  (?<=Policy) [ ] \g<word> - \g<word> / \g<word> / \g<word>
}x
```

(Note that this is restricted to Oniguruma/Onigmo, so it's only going to work in this form in Ruby and a small number of other tools.)

Comment: Thats great, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your expression works just fine, if you like, maybe you could modify that to some expression such as:

```
re = /(?<=Policy\s)[A-Z]+-[A-Z0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/\d+/
str = 'Policy PO-EXW1900000955/00/00'

str.match(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hiAoTD/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hiAoTD/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.